# Laravel socialite - config is null when I extend the provider class

Tags: php, laravel

I use:

"php": "^7.2.5",
"laravel/framework": "^7.0",
"laravel/socialite": "^4.4",
"socialiteproviders/steam": "^3.0"

Trying to extend `\SocialiteProviders\Steam\Provider`:

```
namespace App\Services\NetworkSync;

use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use SocialiteProviders\Steam\Provider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class SteamService extends Provider
{
    const OPENID_SIG = 'openid.sig';
    const OPENID_SIGNED = 'openid.signed';
    const OPENID_ASSOC_HANDLE = 'openid.assoc_handle';
    const OPENID_ERROR = 'openid.error';

    protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
    {
        return (new User())->setRaw($user)->map([
            'id'       => $user['steamid'],
            'nickname' => Arr::get($user, 'personaname'),
            'name'     => Arr::get($user, 'realname'),
            'email'    => null,
            'avatar'   => Arr::get($user, 'avatarmedium'),
        ]);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        //Log::debug($this->getDefaultRequestOptions());
        Log::debug($this->getConfig('api_key'));
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            $error = $this->getParams()['openid.error'] ?? 'unknown error';

            throw new OpenIDValidationException('Failed to validate OpenID login: '.$error);
        }

        return $this->mapUserToObject($this->getUserByToken($this->steamId));
    }

    public function getParams()
    {
        $params = [
            'openid.assoc_handle' => $this->request->get(self::OPENID_ASSOC_HANDLE),
            'openid.signed'       => $this->request->get(self::OPENID_SIGNED),
            'openid.sig'          => $this->request->get(self::OPENID_SIG),
            'openid.ns'           => self::OPENID_NS,
            'openid.mode'         => 'check_authentication',
            'openid.error'        => $this->request->get(self::OPENID_ERROR),
        ];

        $signedParams = explode(',', $this->request->get(self::OPENID_SIGNED));

        foreach ($signedParams as $item) {
            $value = $this->request->get('openid.'.str_replace('.', '_', $item));
            $params['openid.'.$item] = $value;
        }

        return $params;
    }

    public function parseSteamID()
    {
        preg_match(
            '#^https?://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/([0-9]{17,25})#',
            $this->request->get('openid.claimed_id'),
            $matches
        );
        $this->steamId = is_numeric($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 0;
    }
}
```

Defining my own manager:

```
namespace App\Services;

use Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager;
use App\Services\NetworkSync\SteamService;

class NetworkSyncService extends SocialiteManager
{
    public function createSteamDriver()
    {
        $config = $this->app['config']['services.steam'];//Config is valid
        return $this->buildProvider(SteamService::class, $config);
    }
}
```

And I set it in the container:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider;
use App\Services\NetworkSyncService;

class NetworkSyncProvider extends SocialiteServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory', function ($app) {
            return new NetworkSyncService($app);
        });
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, everything works, but the config is not passed, `$this->getConfig('api_key') === null`.
Also I've tried to do just like here https://github.com/JaffParker/Extending-Laravel-Socialite, but the result is same.
**What could be the problem?**

Comment: You tried ```php artisan config:clear```?

Comment: @KurtFriars yes, I tried